# Live obstacle detection iPhone camera - Objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to make a clear area functionality in my camera application. Referring to the image uploaded in link http://www.flickr.com/photos/95148356@N02/8671004387/in/photostream, i need to take a background image without having any obstacles in the white colored area. In the white colored area i need to place another image that is from another source, say a Kinect camera image or so. My objective is to add a live obstacle detection on relative area in my camera application. If some objects appeared on relative area like a rock or tree or something like, my application should give an alert to user say an obstacle is detected or some message like "Clear this area" should be popped out. The picture shouldn't taken with objects in relative area.

Can anyone help me on this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try to re-word the question to make it more comprehendible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is way beyond the scope of the question. Implementing this using the built in iPhone camera is one thing but using an outside live camera source such as Kinect will require extensive knowledge of overlaying a UIView over top of a live AVCaptureSession camera view while also processing the live imagery from a network source. You will need to go step by step to solve this one.

AVCaptureSession will handle the camera live feed.
OpenCV can handle object recognition of a live view.
And networking this will be totally up to you depending on your needs.

Good luck and I hope at least some of this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mark... I already trying opencv to my purpose. But in my thinking OpenCV is only capable for recognizing objects with color, right? If so How could I notify an object which is kept on similar colored background. say a white object in white background. can u please direct me on this? thanks in advance... :)